# Display line numbers before displaying tokens in flex

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer

I'm using flex to read the contents of a cminus file and then display the contents in the following format:
:
tokens
I can display the tokens but when I try to display the line numbers I can only view the line numbers.
My flex file:

```
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int lineNo = 1;
%}
line ^.*\n
letter [a-zA-Z]
digit  [0-9]


%x IN_COMMENT
%%

{line} {printf("%d:\n", lineNo++);} 
{digit}+    {
            printf("found NUM token\n");
            }
"while"    {
            printf("found WHILE token\n");
            }
"else"    {
            printf("found ELSE token\n");
            }
"if"    {
            printf("found IF token\n");
            }
"return"    {
            printf("found RETURN token\n");
            }
"void"    {
            printf("found VOID token\n");
            }
"int"    {
            printf("found INT token\n");
            }
"+"    {
            printf("found PLUS token\n");

            }
"-"    {
            printf("found MINUS token\n");

            }
"*"    {
            printf("found TIMES token\n");

            }
"/"    {
            printf("found OVER token\n");

            }
"<"    {
            printf("found LT token\n");

            }
"<="    {
            printf("found LTEQ token\n");
            }
">"    {
            printf("found GT token\n");
            }
">="    {
            printf("found GTEQ token\n");
            }
"=="    {
            printf("found EQ token\n");
            }
"!="    {
            printf("found NEQ token\n");
            }
"="    {
            printf("found ASSIGN token\n");
            }
";"    {
            printf("found SEMI token\n");

            }
","    {
            printf("found COMMA token\n");

            }
"("    {
            printf("found LPAREN token\n");

            }
")"    {
            printf("found RPAREN token\n");

            }
"["    {
            printf("found LBRACKET token\n");

            }
"]"    {
            printf("found RBRACKET token\n");

            }
"{"    {
            printf("found LBRACE token\n");

            }
"}"    {
            printf("found RBRACE token\n");

            }


[ \t]+
<INITIAL>{
"/*"              BEGIN(IN_COMMENT);
}
<IN_COMMENT>{
"*/"      BEGIN(INITIAL);
[^*\n]+   // eat comment in chunks
"*"       // eat the lone star
\n        yylineno++;
}

{letter}{letter}*  {
            printf("found ID token\n");
            }
. {printf("Unrecognized character");}
%%

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
++argv, --argc;
if ( argc > 0 )
     yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
else
     yyin = stdin;
yylex();
}
```

My input file:

```
/* Sample program
  in CMinus language -
  computes factorial
*/
void main (void)
{
   int x;
   int whileimatit;

   /* read x; { input an integer } */
   x = input();

   /* if x > 0 then { don't compute if x <= 0 } */
   if ( x > 0 ) {
      /*     fact := 1; */
      whileimatit = 1;
      /*   repeat */
      while (x > 0)
      {
     /*     fact := fact * x; */
     whileimatit = whileimatit * x;
     /*     x := x - 1 */
     x = x - 1;
     /*   until x = 0; */
      }
      /* write fact  { output factorial of x } */
      output(whileimatit);

   /* end */
   }
}
```

My output:

```
1:
2:
3:
4:
5:
6:
7:
8:
9:
10:
11:
12:
13:
14:
15:
16:
17:
18:
19:
20:
21:
22:
23:
24:
25:
26:
27:
28:
29:
30:
31:
```

Desired output:

```
1:
2:
3:
4:
5:
found VOID token
found ID token
found LPAREN token
found VOID token
found RPAREN token
6:
found LBRACE token
7:
found INT token
found ID token
found SEMI token
8:
found INT token
found ID token
found SEMI token
9:
10:
11:
found ID token
found ASSIGN token
found ID token
found LPAREN token
found RPAREN token
found SEMI token
12:
13:
14:
found IF token
found LPAREN token
found ID token
found GT token
found NUM token
found RPAREN token
found LBRACE token
15:
16:
found ID token
found ASSIGN token
found NUM token
found SEMI token
17:
18:
found WHILE token
found LPAREN token
found ID token
found GT token
found NUM token
found RPAREN token
19:
found LBRACE token
20:
21:
found ID token
found ASSIGN token
found ID token
found TIMES token
found ID token
found SEMI token
22:
23:
found ID token
found ASSIGN token
found ID token
found MINUS token
found NUM token
found SEMI token
24:
25:
found RBRACE token
26:
27:
found ID token
found LPAREN token
found ID token
found RPAREN token
found SEMI token
28:
29:
30:
found RBRACE token
31:
found RBRACE token
```

If i remove the following line:

```
{line} {printf("%d:\n", lineNo++);}
```

I get the following output:

```
found VOID token
found ID token
found LPAREN token
found VOID token
found RPAREN token

found LBRACE token

found INT token
found ID token
found SEMI token

found INT token
found ID token
found SEMI token



found ID token
found ASSIGN token
found ID token
found LPAREN token
found RPAREN token
found SEMI token



found IF token
found LPAREN token
found ID token
found GT token
found NUM token
found RPAREN token
found LBRACE token


found ID token
found ASSIGN token
found NUM token
found SEMI token


found WHILE token
found LPAREN token
found ID token
found GT token
found NUM token
found RPAREN token

found LBRACE token


found ID token
found ASSIGN token
found ID token
found TIMES token
found ID token
found SEMI token


found ID token
found ASSIGN token
found ID token
found MINUS token
found NUM token
found SEMI token


found RBRACE token


found ID token
found LPAREN token
found ID token
found RPAREN token
found SEMI token



found RBRACE token

found RBRACE token
```

I am unable to print the line numbers together with the output. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `line` as

```
line ^.*\n
```

which means that it matches an entire line. So that is what will happen. Every line will be matched as a `line` token, and no other rule will ever be used.

You could ditch the `line` definition [Note 1], and use the pattern/action rule:

```
\n    {printf("%d:\n", lineNo++);}
```

However, that will trigger at the end of a line rather than the beginning. Also, it will not trigger at the very beginning of the parse, and it will trigger at the end of the last line which is also undesirable.

If you are just trying to implement debugging output, I strongly recommend using Flex's built-in trace facility, enabled with the `-d` option when building your scanner. You might also want to use the `%option yylineno` option, which will tell flex to automatically track the input line number. (Getting flex to do this rather than doing it yourself is a lot more robust, and obviously slightly less work.)

If you really want to output a line number at the *beginning* of every line, you can use a start condition combined with `yyless()` to rescan. Here is a minimal example:

```
%option nodefault noyywrap noinput nounput
%option yylineno

%x BOL
%%
                BEGIN(BOL);                /* Note 2 */
<BOL>.|\n       { yyless(0);               /* Note 3 */
                  printf("Line %d:", yylineno);
                  BEGIN(INITIAL);
                }
\n              putchar('\n'); BEGIN(BOL); /* Note 4 */

  /* Rest of the rules go here. The following is minimal. */
[[:blank:]]+    ;
[^[:blank:]\n]+ printf(" word: '%s'", yytext);
```

#### Notes:

1. In fact, you could ditch most if not all of the definitions. Is `[0-9]` less readable than `{digit}`? I'd say "No", since it has a clear meaning, while `digit` might have been defined as anything. Even clearer would be the built-in character class `[[:digit:]]`.
2. (Line 6) Any action before the first rule is executed every time `yylex` is called. In this case, we are only calling `yylex` once so we can get away with this; if we were actually returning tokens, it would be more convenient to set the initial state from the driver. Or just use `INITIAL` for the start-of-line state, and some other start condition for normal operation.
3. (Lines 7-9) When we're in the BOL state, we respond to any following character, including a newline (which would indicate an empty line). This rule will not be executed if we're at EOF, since in that case there is no following character. The response is to remove the character we just read from the token (which leaves the token empty), then print the message indicating which line we're at. Finally, we change to normal scanning state, which will start with the first character on the line (because of the `yyless`).

   It's tempting to try to do this with the `^` anchor, but that won't work. First, flex does not permit empty patterns, so an anchor by itself is not a valid pattern. It is still necessary to match the following character. However, it will not be possible to rescan that character without once again triggering the anchor rule, since the character will still be at the beginning of a line when rescanned. Hence the use of a start condition.
4. (Line 11) When we hit a newline, we need to change to `BOL` state, so that the next character (if there is one) will trigger the output of the line number. Since this example prints tokens on the same line as the line number, we need to also send the newline to the output to terminate the current line.

Comment: Would it be possible to match the beginning of line anchor (^). I've tried that but i get an unrecognized rule from flex.

Comment: @david: it's tempting but it doesn't work because flex patterns cannot match nothing. You would have to match the first character on the line. But then what? You can't use yyless to restore the character because you would then be back to the first character on the line. Hence the use of the start condition, which can be controlled.

Comment: @david: but the solution is just a curiosity. Or hack. You almost certainly don't need it (see flex debug feature) and if you do, it will probably be easier to print the lineno with each token rather than each line. I only wrote it because it shows some flex features like yyless and start conditions.

Comment: Thanks @rici I was able to use the start condition to keep track of the line numbers.